# How to use poetry in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, python-poetry

### Context

I am currently working on a team project, where we need to train neural networks. Some members are working on their local computer, and some on Colab (for GPU usage). We need to have the same dependencies. I am already familiar in using poetry on a local computer, but not on Colab, and I was wondering how to use it in Colab.

So I did some tests, and I encountered some issues. Maybe I can find some answers here. Thank you in advance!

### Issues

**1st issue**: `poetry add <package>` does not update *pyproject.toml*

I want to add a new package, suppose torch.
According to poetry's documentation, to install a new package, we need to run `poetry add <package>`. Since I run this command for the first time, a virtual environment is created, as well as the *poetry.lock*. But no packages were installed. Moreover, the *poetry.lock* file is updated, but not the *pyproject.toml*. This happens only on Colab. I tried on my local computer, and the command indeed automatically update the *pyproject.toml* file as well.

**2nd issue**: `poetry run pip install <package>` does not update pyproject.toml

Instead, we can install the package with poetry run `pip install <package>`. I saw this command on the following [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/DPaletti/da7729c35ba7f9274c3635849608b7bc). The packages are now installed in the virtual environment, but the *pyproject.toml* was not updated.

Here is a link to the [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fYyWHDHeEThyjUwsm9xgYETPICIf4i-h?usp=sharing) I used for those tests.

Thank you again!

Comment: try do delete the .lock file maybe

Comment: We cannot delete the .lock file, right? And even though we delete it, it will be created again from the .toml file.

Comment: if you delete it it'll just be created again once you update the toml

Comment: No idea about the first issue. The second issue is no issue, because it works as expected. `poetry run <some command>` simply run `<some command>` within the venv created by Poetry. It's a shorthand for 1. activate the venv 2. run a command 3. deactivate the venv.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But yes, it works as expected but the issue here is that the .toml file is not updated automatically. Suppose I had to add a lot of packages, I prefer not to modify the .toml by hand... Doing it automatically (as supposed to with `poetry add` command) is better as it avoids human errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello for everyone reading this post.

I settled on a solution. The main issue was that *pyproject.toml* was not updated automatically, so I just decided to modify it by hand.
Here is the steps for using poetry in Colab, whether you create your own poetry project, or cloning a repo on Github.

https://github.com/elise-chin-adway/poetry-and-colab/blob/main/Using_python_poetry_in_Google_Colab.ipynb

I don't know if it is the best solution or not, but I hope it will help other people :)

Comment: Apparently running poetry commands without the `--no-ansi` option fails and does not install the dependencies. So `!poetry --no-ansi install` and `!poetry --no-ansi add package` should be used instead. It also correctly updates the pyproject.toml file.